# Implementation of Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I am not sure if it's been asked. I am fairly new to hashtables and was wondering about something about the inner class.

I was looking at the hashtable API and it had:

```
static class Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> { }
```

my question is: Is it possible to implement the inner class if it was just:

```
class Entry{ }
```

Would that be possible?

Answer (score 3):

Well that would be a valid nested class, but it wouldn't implement `Map.Entry`, so it couldn't be used for the `Map` methods which require `Map.Entry`, such as [`entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29).

The reason it's declared with the `static` modifier is that a `HashMap.Entry` instance doesn't need to know which `HashMap` it's part of, so there's no benefit in having that extra implicit reference.